# Camel-case column-names: Howto generate a sql column with underscore in EclipseLink like Hibernates ImprovedNamingStrategy does

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I'm moving from Hibernate to EclipseLink.

What I realized is, that Hibernates ddl-generation creates underscore-separated sql-columns for camel-case columns with

```
<property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
```

in my persistence.xml. I like that a lot.

My question is: How can I get EclipseLink to do that?

Jonny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. You have to use the EclipseLink Session-Customizer class.
Explained here (with an example if you scroll down that page): http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/eclipselink-users/msg00094.html

Jonny

Answer (score 0):

Fork this https://gist.github.com/iromu/6864061 . Numbers are not recognized as chars to be surrounded with underscores, you can override the mapping with @Column(name="")